# How to receive and deliver 802.11b/g data link (MAC) broadcast packets to Android applications

Tags: android, broadcast, android-wifi, data-link-layer

I was wondering whether I can receive broadcast packets at MAC level (L2-WiFi) on Android AND deliver such messages to my application which will parse the payload of such packets.

The MAC interface parses all these packets by construction (e.g., beacon); however, I don't know if (where) I can register some "callback" to be invoked whenever the node receives a broadcast packet (i.e., ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) which is not a management WiFi Frame. 
The idea is to have access to some information immediately, possibly even before authentication/association, or if that is not feasible, soon after association and before DHCP has assigned and IP address to my interface.
Yes, there are tcpdump/wireshark like programs but need root privileges, 
while we are looking for a regular way (user privileges) to do it.

Thus, access points can send some information via broadcast packets, 
and clients can receive and parse such information, performing some actions

Any Idea? 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is no way supported by Android SDK API to do that.
Such APIs show just functionalities over level 3, IP.
Thus, it seems to me you cannot access to level 2 in a transparent way.
Actually, I didn't have a look at Android NDK, but I will